# Loop Through Data & Assign Variables in Bash

Tags: bash, loops, variables

I have a text file containing the following information below.  I need to loop through this text file (count.txt) and assign each of these numbers a variable, doesn't matter what name the variable is given.  Is this possible?

> ```
> 4552  856
> 2070  298
> 1993  749
> 4774  248
> 2818  720
> 7912  1204
> 55    16
> 2     2
> 5     3
> 74    19
> 7310  1635
> 278   87
> 88    36
> 53    11
> 1081  252
> 1409  344
> 176   120
> 3219  1052
> 401   83
> 5008  1026
> 1885  276
> 13    9
> 1     1
> 11    5
> 5584  1586
> 10623 2635
> 27    11
> 39    5
> 310   178
> 1742  713
> 5     4
> 14    7
> 3     2
> ```

Comment: Would you not prefer them in an array-like structure? So you could loop through them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, try doing this :

```
while read a b; do echo "$a $b"; done < count.txt
```

If you want to keep all records :

```
array=( $(<count.txt) )
printf '%s\n' ${array[@]}
```